# Android searchable configuration voice search language

Tags: android, searchview, android-search, google-voice-search

I am implementing voice search in my activity using searchable configuration as defined [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html). However setting `android:voiceLanguage="tr"` doesn't seem to work if the locale of the device is different. The search application dialog opens in device's locale as well as the search result. I use `SearchView`, therefore can't catch the `onSearchRequested` function, otherwise I could specify parameters programmatically. The device locale is in Russian so search queries are returned in Cyrillic. How can I force search results to be returned in Turkish or at least English locale?

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:voiceLanguage="tr"
  android:voiceLanguageModel="web_search"
  android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" />
```

**searchview setup**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchWatcher());
    if (searchManager != null)
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

**handling search results**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        searchView.setQuery(query, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging out a little bit I found that `SearchableInfo` class has following property

```
private final int mVoiceLanguageId;
```

which means that they expect you to pass String resource in your `searchable.xml` file. Therefore, specifying `voiceLanguage` from resources solves the problem.

```
android:voiceLanguage="@string/locale"
```